# How do I scroll a WebView to a top of screen point by findNext(true) on Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using the `findAll` method for the first occurrence, then `findNext(true)` for the following markers. The view will automatically scroll to the requested text. But it scrolls to the requested text at the bottom of the device. I want to scroll until the requested text is at top of the screen. Any solution for this?

Do you have any ideas how I could implement this? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well first you try to use `webView.findNext (true)` , then then use `webView.findAll(TEXT);` then `webView.scrollTo (0, webView.getScrollY () +5000)`; (the 5000 is to scroll down) and then use again the `webView.findAll(TEXT);`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for help..............It's working in 2.2 and 3.2 but webView.findAll(TEXT) method it's not working in 4.0.3...

Comment: Can anyone explain this please.